# Not able to open file in Google Cloud Storage after POST upload

Tags: xml, google-cloud-storage

I'm experiencing some trouble uploading a pdf file to my Google Cloud Storage bucket using a REST api (explained here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload). The response gives me a http status 200, but when I try to open or download the pdf file from my bucket it gives me *Invalid or corrupted PDF file*. See my code I'm using below:

```
var hostname = 'https://www.googleapis.com';
var file = 'pathToFile';

var file = WScript.CreateObject('ADODB.Stream');
  file.Type = 1;  
  file.Open();
  file.LoadFromFile(file);
  file.Position = 0;  

var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0');

http.open('POST', hostname + '/upload/storage/v1/b/[myBucket]/o', false);

var boundary = 'foo_bar_baz';

http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary=' + boundary);
http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', [myToken]);

var xml = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
var converter = xml.appendChild( xml.createElement("converter") );
    converter.dataType = "bin.base64";
    converter.nodeTypedValue = file.Read(file.Size);

boundary = '--' + boundary;

var body = boundary + '\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + '{"name":"my.pdf", "mimeType": "application/pdf"}' + '\r\n'
    body += '\r\n' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n' + converter.text + '\r\n';
    body += '\r\n' + boundary + '--'

http.send( body );
```

**----UPDATE----**

See body below:

```
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"name":"myPDF.pdf", "mimeType": "application/pdf"}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/pdf

[base64 binary string]

--foo_bar_baz--
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to evaluate on first sight. I would like you to add some information in an update:
1. Print "body" variable before http.send(body);
2. Could you test it using ["curl" command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) and adding -v?

Comment: Thank you @RubénC. I updated my post with the printed body. I'm afraid I can't use the curl command because I'm working in a environment where downloading command line tools is not possible.

Comment: Based on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#upload-object-json) it looks like the API call header doesn’t include uploadType, as for XML requests. Anyway, I am not familiar with the way that you are performing the request (VBScript probably?) and I wasn’t able to reproduce the issue. I used the “curl” and “client libraries” to upload the objects, described in the page aforementioned, and both of them worked fine.